# Is there a way to get the number of elements in a class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to write a simple jQuery slider, and I need to find the number of elements with a particular class. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $elements = $('.classname'); // cache the result of your query
var numberOfElements = $elements.length; // slightly faster than .size()
```

If you use the [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property you will skip a function call. The [size()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.fn.size) function merely returns `this.length`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".classname").size()
```

should do the trick.

[jQuery docs on .size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
$('.yourClass').length
```